# font awesome 4.0.0 is broken

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

New font awesome 4.0.0 is brocken, Previous version was working perfectly fine. But new version breaks everything below is screenshot.

Chrome Browser :-
[image]

Firefox Browser : - [image]

I have Already done below steps :-

1. Downloaded and unzipped all my font-awesome icons in my directory.
2. I have changed all my icon-name from `icon-*` to `fa-*`.
3. I have verified and checked path of font-awesome and permission, everything is correct.

Note: I am using bootstrap 2.3.2

Am i missing some more setting .. ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it Working, New Font-awesome also asks to add `fa` too with other icon class.

Example :-

```
<i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
```

Missing `fa` will break the icon and will not work.

Friendly advice, if you are using font-awesome icon heavily, do not update without backup. They have renamed and removed few icons.